# Why is my jquery ajax requests performing multiple times?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I am looking at the console in firebug when I click on a function which performs an ajax request. The problem is, that one click of a button should send 1 ajax request, but I get 2 requests being sent!

The code for my js looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.book_now').click(function(){


$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/booking.php',
  data: 'event_id='+event_id+'&time_id='+time_id,
  success: function(data) {
    console.log('inside');
    $('#booking_box_content').html(data);
  }
});


  });
});
```

Which seems pretty straight forward right?

In my console however, I see 2 x GET requests off 1 click.

My button is simply:

```
<div class="book_now"></div>
```

Am I missing something - is there supposed to be 2 GET requests?

Is it by any chance loading up the $(document).ready() function again when the new file is loaded and therefor executing the click function again?

Note: I'm not double clicking the button. It probably doesn't matter, but if I change it to POST it does it twice also.

Edit: the response from booking.php

```
<div id="booking_box_left">
  <h1 class="speaker_name"></h1>
  <h1 class="event_name"></h1>

  <div class="event_start_header">Start</div><div id="event_start_datetime">, </div>
  <div class="cleared"></div>
  <div class="event_end_header">End</div><div id="event_end_datetime">, </div>
  <div class="cleared"></div>
  <div class="event_where_header">Where</div><div id="event_where"><strong></strong><br /><br />
</div>

</div>
<div id="booking_box_right_container">
  <form id="booking_form_1" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="booking_id" value="7a614fd06c325499f1680b9896beedeb" />
    <input type="hidden" name="event_id" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="time_id" value="" />
    <div id="booking_box_right">
      <h1>To reserve your seat</h1>
      <input type="text" name="booking_email" class="enterSomething booking_email" title="Enter your email..." />
      <div class="booking_email_helper">On clicking next a ticket will be held for you for a short period for you to complete your registration.</div>
      <input type="submit" id="next" value="Next" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Note: nothing in this response has any functions being triggered to my knowledge. I'm skeptical that the response is what is firing off the ajax request twice... if the click function is only running once, then it can't possibly be the button is executing the function twice, but the $.ajax() part, namely the success callback which is. I've updated the JS code to show how I structured the console.log() stuff.

**FINAL EDIT:**

My ajax function was wrapped inside of the following:

```
   $('#shade, #booking_box').fadeIn(function(){

     // ajax function

  }
```

I had no idea but it was calling this function for for when the #shade (my thickbox) and the #booking_box came in hence running it TWICE! :(

I feel like such a tool.

Thanks everybody for your help.

Comment: maybe something is not right in your other codes, but that should work just fine and would be just one request. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3KRJX/)

Comment: Any chance you have one `.book_now` nested inside another?

Comment: @KeenLearner: post a screenshot of what you're seeing... and as a sanity check, put a call to console.log() in your click handler, and see if *that* shows up twice.

Comment: Off topic: I'm sure that the names here are just a little misleading, but you know that a **GET** request should never change data on the server right?  "book_now" sounds like an action which will cause a change and thus should be a POST.

Comment: this is supposed to work. problem 100% is in unposted code.

Comment: thanks for that Tster, i'm going to run with POST as I am actually sending data as well which is more hidden with a POST.

@patrick dw, there is no .book_now inside it, there are other div's however, but not with a class of .book_now

@shog9, I did a console.log inside the click function, which performed 1 echo into the console.log, and I added another console.log inside the ajax query itself and got 2 showing up again.

Comment: @KeenLearner, please use jsfiddle to reproduce the problem.  If we see the whole page maybe we can figure out the problem.

Comment: Can you post the request/response data? Perhaps a screenshot of it? What are the response codes? Could there be a redirect involved?

Comment: As I posted earlier, http://www.jsfiddle.net/9cdzW/ demonstrates that the code given does not exhibit the problem described. I guess that's not considered an "answer" around these parts, though.

Comment: @TML: because it doesn't answer anything unless the asker is flat-out *lying*. Hopefully, KeenLearner is eventually able to provide some information that helps us determine the cause of the problem; until then, there is no answer.

Comment: @KeenLearner: I'm with patrick - can you post details on the responses? At this point, I'm thinking there's something very unusual about what this PHP code is sending back, but I'm at a loss as to what could generate two responses for one request...

Comment: @TML, just out of curiosity, is it possible to test what I was doing on that site? ie ajaxing a php file? I thought that could only be used for static stuff.. or would I just refer to server.com/booking.php?

Comment: Why not just ask the post to provide a link to the code in action...? that way instead of saying you need more code, you can get it... An answer that helps the user figure out what is wrong would also be considered an answer in these parts...

Comment: KeenLearner - I see the HTML response you posted. That's not what @Shog9 and I were looking for. Could you post the XHR request/response information that you're seeing in the console?

Comment: Nevermind. I didn't see that you had found the solution. Always a good idea to post as much of the actual relevant code as possible. :o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had my function inside 2 divs with the following JS

```
$('#shade, #booking_box').fadeIn(function(){

 // ajax function

}
```

I didn't realise that by doing this it would execute inside the function 2 times for each div I was fading in...

Solution was:

```
$('#shade').fadeIn(function(){

     $('#booking_box').fadeIn(function() {

        // ajax function

     });

});
```

Answer (score 8):

A few things could be happening:

1. The click handler has been binded twice. Change `$('.book_now').click(function(){` to `$('.book_now').unbind('click').click(function(){` to debug. Later on you could refactor your code to use `$('.book_now').unbind('click',handler).click(handler);`.
2. There is a redirect occurring on the server-side causing there to appear as if there are two ajax requests performed. This would mean `console.log('inside')` would only run once.
3. The click handler is being triggered twice. To debug this, add a breakpoint to your click handler via firebug or webkit's developer tools and debug it manually. You will be able to traverse up the "call stack" and discover if this is the case.

Answer (score 3):

Please remove `document.ready` from your code. Use simple function:

```
$('.book_now').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/booking.php',
    data: 'event_id='+event_id+'&time_id='+time_id,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('inside');
      $('#booking_box_content').html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Why upvote ? You can't bind directly an event on an element that is not loaded. So document.ready should be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone could benefit from my experience.

This is where I got:

```
SCRIPT
    function someFunction(){
      $("#item").change(function(){
        // Function with Ajax Request
      }
    }
```

```
SELECT
onchange="someFunction()"
```

And was causing me a lot of requests. 
To fix it, I removed the `$("#item").change(function(){}` while leaving just the code inside of it

Answer (score 0):

Change you class attribute to id and it won't do it anymore. This is how got around it.